# jQuery self-calling function iteration for scrolling posts

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm attempting to create a post scroller, that moves a container up or down, to show the next post. The type of movement (done with an animation), is decided on factors such as whether the next post is the final one, and whether the size of the post is larger than a viewing container.

I previously used a setInterval for the function but found that I couldn't modify interval times dependant on the variables mention.

Instead, I have opted for function in function iteration, which should allow more flexibility. However it doesn't work!

I have a fully annotated [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jackweath/b7vtrwpc/1/).

As well as putting the code here:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    // An array of HTML elements with the class '.scrNote' (scrolling note)
    var postArr = $('.scrNote');
    // nextSec prepares the script on how to prepare
    var nextSec = 0;
    // Not sure if this is necessary, but tells us the starting position
    var currPos = $('.postContainer').offset().top;
    // topSpace tells the script how far to scroll
    var topSpace = currPos + $(postArr[nextSec]).outerHeight(true);

    function scrollPosts() {
        nextSec++;
        if (nextSec >= postArr.length) {
            // A reset takes place, bring the posts back to the top
            $('.widgPost').scroll();
            $('.widgPost').animate({
                scrollTop: 0
            }, 2000);
            nextSec = 0;
            topSpace = currPos + $(postArr[nextSec]).outerHeight(true);
            // A 4s delay takes place, before the function repeats (calling itself)
            setTimeout(scrollPosts, 4000);
        } else if (postArr[(nextSec - 1)].height() > $('widgPost').height) {
            // A slow scroll takes place when the post is larger than the widget
            $('.widgPost').scroll();
            $('.widgPost').animate({
                scrollTop: topSpace
            }, 10000);
            topSpace = currPos + $(postArr[nextSec]).outerHeight(true);
            // The function begins again as normal, without a delay
            scrollPosts();
        } else {
            // A regular scroll takes place 
            $('.widgPost').scroll();
            $('.widgPost').animate({
                scrollTop: topSpace
            }, 3000);
            topSpace = currPos + $(postArr[nextSec]).outerHeight(true);
            // A 4s delay takes place, before the function repeats (calling itself)
            setTimeout(scrollPosts, 4000);
        }
    }

    // The function should be called here
    scrollPosts();

});
```

```css
.widgPost h1, h2, h3 {
    margin: 0;
}
.widgPost {
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    position: relative;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
.postContainer {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.scrNote {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100px;
    background: yellow;
    position: relative;
    display:block;
    margin: 0 0 16px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="widgPost">
    <div class="postContainer">
        <div class="scrNote">
             <h1>Hello!</h1>
Hello here is some text</div>
        <div class="scrNote">
             <h1>Next post!</h1>
Hello here is some more text...</div>
        <div class="scrNote">
             <h1>Next new post!</h1>
Hello here is some more text...</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The console showed a few errors... Mainly, you were missing () after one of the height functions.

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {


    function scrollPosts() {
        //Some intial setup
        var postArr = $('.scrNote');
        var nextSec = 0;
        var isPaused = false;
        var currPos = $('.postContainer').position().top;
        var topSpace = currPos + $(postArr[nextSec]).outerHeight(true);



        nextSec++;
        if (nextSec >= postArr.length) {
            $('.widgPost').scroll();
            $('.widgPost').animate({
                scrollTop: 0
            }, 2000);
            nextSec = 0;
            topSpace = currPos + $(postArr[nextSec]).outerHeight(true);
            setTimeout(scrollPosts, 4000);
        } else if (postArr[(nextSec - 1)].height > $('widgPost').height) {
            $('.widgPost').scroll();
            $('.widgPost').animate({
                scrollTop: topSpace
            }, 10000);
            topSpace = currPos + $(postArr[nextSec]).outerHeight(true);
        } else {
            console.log(nextSec); 
            $('.widgPost').scroll();
            $('.widgPost').animate({
                scrollTop: topSpace
            }, 3000);
            topSpace = currPos + $(postArr[nextSec]).outerHeight(true);
            setTimeout(scrollPosts, 4000);
        }
    };

    scrollPosts();

});
```

Here's a scrolling fiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/jackweath/b7vtrwpc/1/

I'm not sure if that's the behavior you wanted exactly, but at least the function is running. You should be able to take it from there.

Answer (score 0):

You had problem with below line:

```
else if (postArr[(nextSec - 1)].height() > $('widgPost').height)
```

You were getting error `height()` is not a function **which is obvious unless you wrap your `postArr` with `$`**. So if you wrap your `postArr` inside `$` as below then you can definitely use `height()` since `height()` is a `jquery` function.

```
else if ($(postArr[(nextSec - 1)]).height() > $('widgPost').height)
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/b7vtrwpc/3/)**

Or just remove it and use it as latter one

```
else if (postArr[(nextSec - 1)].height > $('widgPost').height)
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/b7vtrwpc/2/)**

That will fix the issue.

Comment: The jQuery documentation does in fact ask for [height()](http://api.jquery.com/height/). Not sure why this worked as of yet, but thank you!

Comment: @JackWeatherilt.. It will definitely, **if you wrap you `postArr` with `$`**.. Check this **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/b7vtrwpc/3/)** too.. :)

Comment: The problem was a missing set of brackets after one of the height functions and missing selectors for the postArr. I would like to correct you in saying that **.height() is most definitely a function**. Your solution initial solution is actually a quick fix, that is ignored by the browser.

Comment: @JackWeatherilt. As I said earlier you must need `$` wrapped for `postArr` for `height()` to be functional since its a `jquery` function!! I would like to stay with my statement provided a condition added to that as mentioned in my answer!! Even though you are assigning `postArr` with `$('.scrNote');` it should be functional but not sure why it is  not taking jquery `context` without wrapping in `$`. Anyways its a nice question and demo indeed!! Happy Coding!!